# Understanding Ahlfors's proof for the Gauss-Lucas's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation

Ahlfors gives the following proof for the Gauss-Lucas theorem:

> **Theorem:** If all zeros of a polynomial $P(z)$ lie in a half plane, then all zeros of the derivative $P'(z)$ lie in the same half plane

> From $P(z) = a_n(z - \alpha_1)(z - \alpha_2)\cdots(z - \alpha_n)$ we obtain $\frac{P'(z)}{P(z)} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z - \alpha_n}$. Suppose that the half plane $H$ is defined as the part of the plane where $\mathrm{Im}((z - a)/b) < 0$. If $\alpha_k$ is in $H$ and $z$ is not, we have then that $\mathrm{Im}((z - \alpha_k)/b) = \mathrm{Im}((z - a)/b) - \mathrm{Im}((\alpha_k - a)/b) > 0$. But the imaginary parts  of the reciprocal numbers have opposite sign. Therefore, under the same assumption, $\mathrm{Im}(b(z - \alpha_k)^{-1}) < 0$. If this is true for all $k$, we conclude that $\mathrm{Im}(\frac{bP'(z)}{P(z)}) = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Im}(b(z - \alpha_k)^{-1}) < 0$ and consequently $P'(z) \neq 0$.

What I don't understand from this proof is that at what point do we show that the zeros of $P'(z)$ lie in the same half plane? The end statement shows that $P'(z)$ is non-zero in $H$, but that is not what we ought to show.

Comment: Read more carefully: the proof shows that if every $\alpha_k$ is in $H$ *and $z$ is not*, then $P’(z) \neq 0$. Thus if the $\alpha_k$ are all in $H$, the roots of $P’$ are in $H$.

Comment: @Aphelli Ah, true. But does Ahlfors use the fundamental theorem of algebra implicitly? I don't see any other way why the final conclusion would then imply the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It proved the proposition by contrapositive. Ahlfors considered any arbitrary $z\notin H$, and showed that $\alpha_k\in H$ for all $k$ implies $P’(z)\neq0$ because in particular the imaginary part isn’t zero. So, all the zeroes $z$ of $P’$, if they exist, cannot have $z\notin H$ (therefore $z\in H$...). You maybe missed: “*and $z$ is not*”.

Comment: You are probably right about the missing part. But does Ahlfors use implicitly the fundamental theorem of algebra? I don't see any other way to conclude the proof.

Comment: @SickSeries The proof is already concluded. It need not be the case that $p'(z)$ has any zeroes at all, since it might be constant. But, any zeroes, if they do exist, cannot be not in $H$ (as the proof shows) hence they must be in $H$

Comment: I suppose you could claim that they used the fundamental theorem of algebra and the polynomial division theorem to express $p$ as a product of factors, but this is a trivial detail